# Some scss properties disable in component based styling in nextjs

Tags: reactjs, sass, next.js

I am using following css property in my component styling file in NextJs or if i import my main styles.scss file in my any component.styles.scss file it gives same error:

```
input[type="date"] {
  display: block;

  /* Solution 1 */
  -webkit-appearance: textfield;
  -moz-appearance: textfield;
  min-height: 1.2em;

}
```

But it throws following error as show in image:

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DzzJU.png)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the logs, the error seems to be coming from `confirm-funding.module.scss`

By design, CSS modules are scoped CSS classes and you'll need to import them within a JS file and apply them to an HTML element’s className. In your case, you seem to be using a global selector (`button`) inside `confirm-funding.module.scss` which is causing the error.

You can either opt-out from CSS modules or use class selector.

Selectors like html, body, button, input etc are global (unscoped) selectors; in addition, they also are not valid scoped classes (like how .exampleClassName is scoped to a div element in the example above). Next expects CSS modules to be pure in that they don’t produce side effects (like altering the body style based upon a page being loaded or a particular component being loaded -- in the example above, the body is outside of the component-level scope). The reason pure stylesheets are enforced/encouraged is because they allow CSS to be split chunked (when you land on a page, you only download the styles necessary to view that particular page, instead of downloading everything at once).

More details on [css modules](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules#css-modules)

Comment: Then what changes i can bring to my files to remove that error?